# Display nested function with which-function-mode in Emacs

Tags: emacs

Turning which-function-mode on in Emacs displays the function name in the status bar of the current function where the cursor is at.  However, when there're nested functions or method inside class, only the outer most function is displayed.

For example, I have the following class in C++.

```
class Foo
{
   void func1()
   {
      ...
   }
};
```

When the cursor is inside func1(), the class name Foo is displayed on the status bar.  How do I make it to display Foo plus func1?  Something like Foo.func1 or Foo::func1 would be good.

Comment: Which version of emacs are you using? Because I am using 23.1.1 and when I turn which-funcion-mode on, the class.function is showed on emacs status bar

Answer (score 2):

The which-func feature uses imenu features by default to get it's display name.  I don't think there is a way to get the feature you're looking for by default.

If you install [CEDET](http://cedet.sf.net), it can override the which-func feature to get names using it's parser system, then it will do exactly what you describe, though it uses "." by default.

Comment: Boy I'd love to be able to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You might try it with library [`imenu+.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/imenu%2b.el) loaded as well.  Dunno whether that will help.  Otherwise, you can try tweaking the definition of `which-function` so that it uses a function such as `symbol-name-near-point`, which is in library [`thingatpt+.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/thingatpt%2b.el).  See also [Thing At Point+](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ThingAtPointPlus).